# Dynamically loading blog posts from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I'm sure I'm doing this wrong, and that there's a better way of doing this.

I just finished making a food blog website. Posts are uploaded into a database. The HTML files are generated using the information from the SELECT statement, when they are needed.

Basically, I didn't think it was smart to create a new HTML file and store pages that way, but rather create them on the fly.

This is my (terrible) method:

1. User clicks on link or types URL
2. URL is structured like so: www.website.com/name-of-post
3. There is no HTML file called name-of-post.php so it redirects with a 404 error.
4. On that page I check to see if 'name of post' exists in the database.
5. If it does, generate the file. Else, show 404 error page.

This method also means that the pages aren't indexed by google, so people will not be able to search a recipe that way.

I know this can't be right. So is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Please (re-)read the [help] to see how to ask. We need a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

Well, you just discovered the reason PHP was invented 20 years ago. It's a templating engine that allows you to **dynamically generate web pages**.

Storing content in your database is generally fine. Most content is just data. However, building a web page using that content is an entirely different matter. There's neither a need to generate an actual .html file on your filesystem nor a need to store an .html file (in its entirety) in your database to do so.

The concept of [templating in PHP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoEIU8fshn4) is that you create the format separate from the content, such that the format can always be changed, and the content can always be plugged in regardless.

For example, here's a very simple template.

```
<h1>Hello <?=$name?></h1>
<p>Today is <?=date('l F jS, Y')?>.</p>
```

The format of this page will always be the same, regardless of the content, which are the variables that we could easily plug into the template from our database. Your problem is no different. You can store templates, written as simple HTML and PHP code that just *plug-in* the content with some variables (likely populated by the data in your database).

The concept of dynamically creating URLs is relatively similar. You can tell your web server to redirect all requests to a main PHP script (typically referred to as a [front-controller](https://github.com/PatrickLouys/no-framework-tutorial/blob/master/01-front-controller.md)) like your index.php, and have that script check the database for the request URI (using something like `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, for example) and based on that information you can pull in the needed content from your database, use the template to generate the output, and out comes the page for the client.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. I have various templates that I use in step 5 - I get the data from the database and insert it into a template. I understand I can set my web server up to redirect all request to a single page for processing - eliminating the 404 errors - which is good. However, does this solve the problem of my pages not being indexed by google?

Comment: It's unclear whether or not that's even a problem. If the request actually produces a 404 HTTP response code from the server then Google will see it as "**Page Not Found**". Indexing pages that the server states don't exist is rather pointless for any search engine. However, is that what is actually happening on your server? The server responds with an HTTP 404 Page Not Found? I somehow doubt that this is the case. You probably just mean you're handling the 404 not found internally, which isn't good, but also isn't privy to the end-user.

Comment: Oh I see, so Google will index a page if it "technically" isn't an HTML file? I get a 404 error, but pretend like it's okay and show the page.